# Bash Printf reversed the order of arguments

Tags: bash, printf

It's a weird scenario I came across and I'm quite confused

```
$ printf "%s:%s\n" "$(date)" "$(python -V)"
Python 2.7.10
Thu 10 Oct 2019 19:05:11 EDT:
```

Whereas with other commands I get an expected result

```
$ printf "%s:%s\n" "$(date)" "$(hostname)"
Thu 10 Oct 2019 19:04:53 EDT:alvy.local
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`python -V` prints to stderr. Use `2>&1` to redirect the output to stdout so it can be captured.

```
$ printf "%s:%s\n" "$(date)" "$(python -V 2>&1)"
```

Comment: Hi, that makes sense! But I can't find the documents where it explained that it points to the stderr. Do you mind sharing the link?

Comment: I don't have a link, it's just the behavior I observe: `python -V >/dev/null` prints the version while `python -V 2>/dev/null` prints nothing.